# Merge multiple datasets with conditions in one data step?

Tags: sas

I have 3 datasets that are linked by an ID column

version SAS 9.2

D1 (2 cols) (ID col is unique)

```
ID Value
1 81
2 81
3 82
4 82
5 81
6 78
```

D2 ( 3 cols)

```
ID Line Code
1 1 651
1 2 652
1 3 655
2 1 650
2 2 652
3 1 651
3 2 655
3 3 651
3 4 658
4 1 651
4 2 651
```

D3 (2 cols)

```
ID Vcode
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 C
3 B
3 D
```

I want a resultant data set that has cols from all datasets and the criteria is

1. Value should be 81 or 82 from D1
   **And** if record only contains 'line' with 'code' 651, 652, 655 or 656, from D2 then we exclude it from the final dataset.
   **And** All records from D3 that meet above two criteria

Resultant dataset would be like

```
ID Value Line Code Vcode
2 81 1 650 A
2 81 2 652 C
3 82 1 651 B
3 82 2 655 D
3 82 3 651 -
3 82 4 658 -
```

I am writing data steps for each step but I am looking for one data step or proc SQL that can combine all the logic

**

> Edited 10/20/2017

**

The below is what i have done. The datasets D1...D3 are just aliases for my questions and below is the actual.

I need to get records from D2 in my second proc sql statement where not all 'line's have one of the four 'code' 651, 652, 655 or 656 but my proc sql is not correct, i think. I want to exclude those. That is why my resultant dataset does not have records where 'ID' is 1 and 4. As far as doing it one datastep is nice to have but more than one is fine.

```
libname SAF "F:\Databases\SAF\sasdata\2015";
libname  out "F:\projects\0122_Oct17\SASDATA"; 


Options symbolgen mlogic mprint; 
Options obs=max;  

proc contents data=SAF.Hosp_claimsj_lds;
run;


Data OUT.Hospice_TOB_81x82x;
    Set SAF.Hosp_claimsj_lds (keep = CLAIM_NO PRVDR_NUM CLM_THRU_DT CLM_FAC_TYPE_CD CLM_SRVC_CLSFCTN_TYPE_CD CLM_FREQ_CD CLM_PMT_AMT);
    WHERE CLM_FAC_TYPE_CD = '8' and CLM_SRVC_CLSFCTN_TYPE_CD in ('1','2'); /* TOB 81x and 82x */
    TOB = CATT(OF CLM_FAC_TYPE_CD CLM_SRVC_CLSFCTN_TYPE_CD CLM_FREQ_CD);
Run;

proc sql;
    create table out.Hospice_TOB_81x82x_ValCd as
    select  *
 from SAF.Hosp_instval_lds
    Where Claim_no in (Select Claim_no from out.Hospice_TOB_81x82x);
quit;


proc sql;
    create table out.Hospice_TOB_81x82x_RevCd as
    select  *
 from SAF.Hosp_revenuej_lds
    Where Claim_no in (Select Claim_no from out.Hospice_TOB_81x82x)
          and REV_CNTR NOTIN ('651', '652', '655','656');
quit;
```

Comment: Please post what you've attempted thus far, including your code and log and what issues you're having.

Comment: It's unlikely that you will be able to get this output in a single step. It implies that the end result is produced by matching tables from the three tables a one-to-one, hence `data` step `merge`; however your second condition will require some SQL.

Comment: The question needs a bit more clarification. How can code appear in the resulting file and be excluded in all **and** condition? Maybe you mean that it's excluded in join of **D1 and D2** but not D2 and D3?

Comment: @Reeza  - Thank you for your comments. I have clarified my question further.

Comment: @pinegulf - Thank you for your comments. I have clarified my question further

Comment: @user2877959 - Thank you for your comments. I have clarified my question further

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which produces almost the required. result. I hope you're able to modify it to suit your need.

```
data D1;
    input ID Value @@;
    cards; 
    1 81 2 81 3 82 4 82 5 81 6 78
    ;
run;

data D2; 
    input ID Line Code @@;
    cards;
    1 1 651 1 2 652 1 3 655 2 1 650 2 2 652 3 1 651 
    3 2 655 3 3 651 3 4 658 4 1 651 4 2 651
    ;
run;

data D3;
    input ID Vcode $ @@;
    cards; 
    1 A  1 B 2 A 2 C 3 B 3 D
    ;
ruN;

data one;
    merge D1(in=a) D2(in=b); 
    by id;
    if a and b;
    if value in (81 82);
    if code not in (651 652 655 656 );
run;
data two; 
    merge D2 D3;
    by id;
run;

data almost wanted;
    merge one (in=a) two(in=b);
    by id ;
    if a;
run;
```

Comment: How can i get all records from D2 for ID from D1 (where Value = 81/82) where i exclude records if all 'Line' for an 'ID' have 'code' value in one of 651, 652, 655 or 656 and want to include everything else. If at least one 'line' for an 'ID' has a code not in 651, 652, 655 or 656 then i want to include all 'line' for that 'ID'

Comment: @user176047 Thanks for the clarification. Even with this, the question seem to be beyond my skill. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: I exported it to SQL server via ODBC and did my extraction using T-SQL.